# convert file from .csv to .txt with change in format delete specific column and row header

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have data in .csv file in below format

| datetime | symbol | open | high | low | close | volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2005-03-10 09:15:00 | NSE:ATUL | 85.59 | 89.00 | 85.19 | 86.84 | 73582 |
| 2005-03-11 09:15:00 | NSE:ATUL | 89.44 | 89.80 | 85.50 | 85.94 | 153945 |
| 2005-03-14 09:15:00 | NSE:ATUL | 86.90 | 88.75 | 84.00 | 84.65 | 73539 |
| 2005-03-15 09:15:00 | NSE:ATUL | 85.00 | 85.94 | 82.00 | 82.40 | 79053 |

I want to create a new .txt or .csv file with formatting given below

1. 1st - I want to remove 'symbol' column
2. 2nd - want remove header row i.e. datetime|symbol|open.....
3. 3rd - want to change 'datetime' column date and time format to YYYYMMDD
4. 4th - separate each column with ";"

desired format sample given below for understanding.

```
20050310;   85.59;    89.00;   85.19;    86.84;  73582  
20050311;   89.44;     89.80;    85.50;    85.94;  153945  
20050314;   86.90;     88.75;    84.00;    84.65;   73539  
20050315;  85.00;     85.94;    82.00;    82.40;   79053
```

So far I have tried following code but unable to do next to find desired format

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('ATUL.csv')

print("Original 'ATUL.csv' CSV Data: \n")

print(data)

data.drop('symbol', inplace=True, axis=1)

print("\nCSV Data after deleting the column 'symbol':\n")

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

> 2nd - want remove header row i.e. datetime|symbol|open.....

You can use `header` to exclude header when exporting.

> 3rd - want to change 'datetime' column date and time format to YYYYMMDD

You can convert `datetime` column to datetime type then use `dt.strftime` to change format.

> 4th - separate each column with ";"

You can use `sep` to specify delimiter when exporting.

```py
data.drop('symbol', inplace=True, axis=1)
data['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['datetime']).dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
data.to_csv('output.txt', sep=';', header=None, index=False)
```

```
20050310;85.59;89.0;85.19;86.84;73582
20050311;89.44;89.8;85.5;85.94;153945
20050314;86.9;88.75;84.0;84.65;73539
20050315;85.0;85.94;82.0;82.4;79053
```

Comment: Superb!! can you also tell me how can do the same for multiple files in one go?

Comment: @DhirendraRawat Maybe a for loop?

Comment: yes, I mean same way how can I convert multiples files in one go. for example files name ATUL.csv, ISEC.csv, HLL.csv all with similar format

Comment: above code is perfect for converting one file, I was looking if I can do the same with the multiple files in one go to get multiple .txt files

Comment: @DhirendraRawat Just use a for loop: `for filename in ['ATUL.csv', 'ISEC.csv', 'HLL.csv']` and read with `data = pd.read_csv(filename)`.